# facebook unsupported post request

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I have logged in a user to my app from `FB.login` now I want to post to the user timeline on the behalf of user. I want to upload a video to the user timeline. I am doing something like:

```
FB.api(
    `/${user_id}/videos`,
    "POST",
    {
        "file_url": video,
        "description": description,
        "thumb": video_thumbnail,
        "title": title,


    },
    function (response) {
      console.log("fb response")
      console.log(response)
      if (response && !response.error) {
        /* handle the result */
        console.log("video upload response")
        console.log(response)
      }
    }, {scope: ['user_videos', 'user_actions.video']});
```

When I do this it is giving me error saying `code: 100
fbtrace_id: "F1BDJWtcTXl"
message: "Unsupported post request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api"
type: "GraphMethodException"`

Why I am getting this error ??

Help is appriciated ..

Thank you

Comment: Do you really have ` in there around the first parameter? And why do people keep trying to pass the scope to `FB.api`, that makes no sense – you need to ask for permissions during login, not when making an API call.

Answer (score 0):

Use `/me/videos` instead of `/${user_id}/videos` and use single (or double) quotes instead of "`".

Also, you need `publish_actions` only, and you need to use the scope parameter with `FB.login`. `FB.api` is just an API call.

Here´s an example for the login: http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-javascript-sdk-login/

And here´s the link to the docs for uploading videos: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user/videos/#Creating

Someone suggested that the App may be in sandbox/dev mode, no sure why this should be a problem but here´s the thread: [How to fix "Unsupported post request" when posting to FB fan page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25482760/how-to-fix-unsupported-post-request-when-posting-to-fb-fan-page)

Comment: I changed according to your suggestion.. I used `/me/videos` instead and now it is giving me error like:
`code: 2500
fbtrace_id: "CJZCKpMznka"
message: "An active access token must be used to query information about the current user."
type: "OAuthException"`

Comment: then make sure your access token is active and includes publish_actions: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/