# Facebook video upload invalid foramat. It should be an image file data

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

Here I am trying to upload a video to user profile. 
I have set up javascript sdk and my authentication works well .

I have the following code here..

```
FB.api(
        `/${user_id}/videos`,
        "POST",
        {
            "file_url": video,
            "description": description,
            "thumb": video_thumbnail,
            "title": title,


        },
        function (response) {
          console.log("fb response")
          console.log(response)
          if (response && !response.error) {
            /* handle the result */
            console.log("video upload response")
            console.log(response)
          }
        });
```

Here I get the following error ..

`code: 100
fbtrace_id: "FD5tVyrH9bS"
message: "(#100) Invalid format. It should be an image file data."
type: "OAuthException"`

I am using `file_url` and passing `url` to my video. I guess it should upload the video..

Thank you for the response

Comment: are you guys using the same code? why not use /me/videos instead? > http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35744180/facebook-unsupported-post-request/

Comment: either way, impossible to help without even knowing what the file_url looks like.

Comment: @luschn my url looks like `https://someurl/videos/myvideo.mp4`

Answer (score 1):

I confirm that you must post  image file data in source field when posting to Facebook.
You can test by use Postman.
This is example:

```js
var fs = require("fs");
var request = require("request");

var options = { method: 'POST',
  url: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.11/2011156779127713/thumbnails',
  headers: 
   { 'Postman-Token': '6c17c103-d8f6-47a5-713b-b3709dde762d',
     'Cache-Control': 'no-cache',
     'content-type': 'multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW' },
  formData: 
   { access_token: 'test',
     is_preferred: 'true',
     source: 
      { value: 'fs.createReadStream("./Downloads/923249_818835191462845_1528674847924045075_n.jpg")',
        options: 
         { filename: './Downloads/923249_818835191462845_1528674847924045075_n.jpg',
           contentType: null } } } };

request(options, function (error, response, body) {
  if (error) throw new Error(error);

  console.log(body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't the video or the URL, it's the `thumb` parameter.

The `thumb` parameter needs to be 'file data', **not** the URL.

As to what format the image needs to be in..please let me know if you find out! I'm asking the same [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43828144/how-to-upload-video-thumbnail-to-facebook-graph-api-net).

The facebook API is terrible...

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question? I've tried base64 encoding, file open/close, PIL and none seem to work for this data. Thanks already. :)

Comment: No luck so far I'm afraid.