# How to upload video thumbnail to Facebook graph API (.NET)?

Tags: c#, facebook-graph-api

I'm POSTing a video using the Facebook graph API [video endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video#Creating), everything working fine. But I can't figure out how to provide a custom thumbnail. The API says to provide a `thumb` parameter:

> The video thumbnail raw data to be uploaded and associated with a video.

But what exactly does 'raw data' mean? I've tried encoding it as base 64 (with and without `data:image/jpeg;base64,` prepended, but always get the error:

> OAuthException
>
> (#100) Invalid image format. It should be an image file data.

I get the same using the graph API explorer.

I'm using C# (via ASP.NET Web API).

I see similar questions online about other languages, but no .NET friendly solution.

API version 2.9.

Thanks

Comment: Raw data means raw data - basically, the byte values that the image file on your HDD would contain. Base64 is not raw data.

Comment: I tried making the property of type byte[], but then when I passed it to JSON.NET for serialisation, it came out with exactly the same base64 string. Which makes sense, as JSON doesn't support binary - imagine how inefficient it would be to send binary... "0100111010001..." as a string

Comment: That’s why we use bytes, not bits. But that still has nothing whatsoever to do with base64.

Comment: I'm not sure what your point is. Please enlighten me how you send bytes over JSON.